# Instance Methods in Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, methods

friends, I have 2 Instance Methods in Obj-C and I need to convert it in Swift:

```
- (NSArray<GLMapVectorObject*> *_Nullable)createVectorObjectsFromGeoJSON:(NSString *)geoJSON
```

and converted in Swift as `let tmpObj = mapView?.createVectorObjectsFromGeoJSON("{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\": [25.29131, 53.88995]}")!` - Create an array of GLMapVectorObject from string - and it's working good, but I don't know how to convert that method - creates style object:

```
- (GLMapVectorStyle *_Nullable)createStyle:(NSString *)style
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but may be this is what you want?
func createStyle(style: String?) -> GLMapVectorStyle?

Comment: yes, but when I try to use that as mapView?.createStyle("{icon-image:\"autobus.svgpb\";icon-scale:0.5;icon-tint:green;}") I see error:  Value of type 'GLMapView' has no member 'createStyle', but in GLMapView.h it was declared: /**
 @abstract Creates style object.
 @param style NSString with style rules in MapCSS format
 @discussion One style could be used with many `GLMapVectorObjects`.
 */
-(GLMapVectorStyle *_Nullable) createStyle:(NSString *)style;

Comment: I'm not sure that I have understand your question. If you are converting ObjC code to Swift, then you also need to declare(create) GLMapView Swift class, and add  createStyle function in it.

Comment: so, i have framework in Obj-C and I connected it by CocoaPods in my project in Swift. So, all methods I can call in my code in swift, but when I try to call createStyle() I see error Value of type 'GLMapView' has no member 'createStyle'

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason for the error message you are seeing is that the interface declaration of class `GLMapVectorStyle` is not visible to Swift via the bridging header.  I'm also assuming that the `createStyle` method is available to Swift through the bridging header.